# How to create a custom grouped "axis" for a matrix chart using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I've created a matrix chart using D3.js and I'm having a bit of difficulty creating a sort of grouped "axis" (although I'm not sure I can call it an axis?).

This [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/nakek/3/edit) shows the current route I've chosen.  Essentially what I've done is to create 3 separate lines to create the "axis".  Ideally I would like to use the d3.axis object but I'm not sure how I would go about achieving this.

Although this current method does work it feels dirty - I also have concerns about scaling.  Does anyone have a better suggestion of how to approach this?

The end result is something along these lines (notice labels below lines):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
.scale(x).tickValues(xVals)
```

where xVals are the array of values

[Here](http://rendomescalplot.appspot.com/) may be this demo will help you